# Custom progress dialog showing error

Tags: android

I have an application in which i have to show a progress dialog without the title and message. I only need to show the progressbar animation that comes, but in the center.

I am trying to put the following code:

```
        ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(this);
    pd.setContentView(R.layout.customprogressdialog);
    pd.show();
```

but i am getting the error that request Feature must be called before `setContentView'. i have tried doing this also but still i am getting an error.

How do i achieve what i want? What is the logic behind calling requestfeature before setcontentview?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a ProgressDialog if that's not what you need. If you want to give a dialog a custom layout, start from scratch with a Dialog or AlertDialog. I think that will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that some part of the work done by the `show` method on the dialog object calls `requestWindowFeature`: without digging much deeper into the Android platform's guts it is going to be rather hard to tell where exactly that takes place.

You are better served just creating your own Dialog class with your custom layout and adding a method to set the progress bar value.

Comment: the thing is that i am not showing a progress bar..  i am showing the round progress bar.. so there is no update in the progress value that i need to take care of. Ofcourse i can do the custom progress dialog.. but is there an easier way to achieve what i want to do?

Comment: Well, if there is no update then that makes it even easier: you don't need an update method at all: you just create your dialog once and then dismiss it once you are done with it. I don't believe there is an easier way around this, unfortunately: that call to `show()` does a bunch of things in the Android platform code that you don't really get to control, so no ducking that.